# how to add two classes that contain integers and return the result in the form of that same class

Tags: java

Hi everybody I need little help I'm stuck
I created a class called octet that consists of an array of 8 bits binary numbers and now I want to create a method that add 2 octet numbers but can't figure out a way to do so. this is the class:

```
public class Octet {
    
    int[] x = new int[8];
      
    // constructor that takes a binary number in the form of a string. 
    Octet(String s){
        if (s.length() != 8) {
            System.out.println("Too few or too many characters");
            return;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            if (s.charAt(i) == '1') {
                x[7 - i] = 1;
            }
            else {
                x[7 - i] = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    // method to convert an octet to string
    String octetToString() {
        String result = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            if (x[i] == 1) {
                result = "1" + result;
            }
            else {
                result = "0" + result;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    // this is where I got stuck
    Octet sum(Octet y){
        octet result = new Octet("00000000")
        // how do I add two octets and return the result in the form of octet?
    }
}
```

Can anyone one explain this to me. I tried to convert the two octets to string using the method octetToString() and I tried to use integers but there is always a type problem. I need to return Octet

Comment: the result of what? Just instantiate two of them, and you'llhave two of them

Comment: How do I add two Octets (two binary numbers);

Comment: Is this for a course assignment? Do you know how to add binary numbers? Try to think it through starting with two numbers that are both one bit long. There are four possibilities. What are they?

Comment: I know how to add two binary numbers sir but the problem is that I'm not dealing with two binary integers it would be easy if it was like that. It's the octet that I have to add. so basically i have to add two binary octets and the function returns an Octet. That's why I'm stuck and confused

Comment: let's say I have Octet o1 and o2 both are 8 bits and I want to add them together I can use the method octetToString() to convert them from Octet to strings then I can add them but how do I return the result as an Octet not as a string without using another converstion method

Comment: No answer guys?

Comment: It appears that a given Octet is intended to represent a single 8-bit integer value.  You can use a single int rather than int[].  If you prefer to model the value as array then then consider using a boolean[] snice you are modeling bits rather than numbers.

Comment: Still doesn't answer my question sir but thank you anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
Octet sum(Octet y){
    
    //Convert this octet and argument octet to decimal format
    int o1 = Integer.parseInt(y.octetToString(), 2);
    int o2 = Integer.parseInt(octetToString(), 2);

    //Sum decimal numbers as usual
    int sum = o1 + o2;
    
    //Convert sum to binary number
    String binarySum = Integer.toBinaryString(sum);

    //Check if result binary sum is ok
    if(binarySum.length() > 8){
        //Sum of these 2 octets is not an octet (has more than 8 digits)
        throw new RuntimeException("Shit");
    }
    
    //Result binary sum may have less digits than 8, 
    //so fill missing places with zeros
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(binarySum);

    while(result.length() < 8)
        result.insert(0, "0");
    
    //Create octet
    return new Octet(result.toString());
}
```

Note that it can be done only when sum of 2 octets is also an octet.

Comment: oooh, thank you so much man finally. You saved me. I don't know what's wrong with me every time feel like I'm starting to understand programming something new blocks me it's so frustrating. thank you again @Jan Rozenbajgier

Comment: @sam No problem! There's always something what's blocking (even if you are an expert, but then it happens less often). That's why this site is so awesome! Don't worry and practice. If you appreciate the help you can give vote up and accept my answer. (I'll earn the reputation) thx.

Comment: For sure you deserve it, been stuck for two days and it seemed like I'll never figure it out but you saved me